# How can I convert this code from using a for loop to while loop in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert this code to use a while loop, can someone please help, appreciated.

```
Adder <-function(n)
{c<-0;
for (i in 1:n)
{
c <- c+i;
}
return(c);
```

Comment: Do you mean while c < 0, add i to c?

Comment: @HAPPYDUMMY Please include those details in your main post ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73658391/edit) your post, not as a comment). Comments get deleted, and this is important information helping us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you have to use an explicit `for` loop? Would `Adder <- function(n) sum(1:n)` not be allowed? One of R's strengths is the ability to use vectorised functions (like `sum`).

Comment: @Bushidov No, there's nothing wrong with it, and using `c` as a variable name is often (though really not here) the natural choice.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
Adder1 <- function(n){
  c <- 0
  x <- 1
  while(x <= n){
    c <- x + c
    x <- x + 1
  }
  return(c)
}
```

Comment: The issue with using an explicit loop aside, using `while` seems unnecessarily complicated. Why not `Adder <- function(n) { ret <- 0; for (i in 1:n) ret <- ret + i; ret }`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, the OP asked for while loop, so one version of that.